# View Component with validation errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When i submit a form with incorrect data within a view component, my view component does not display any errors on the page.

So is it possible for a view component to return validation errors ?

### View Component

```
<div class="card-block">
    <form class="form-inline-custom" asp-controller="BragOption" asp-action="Create" method="post" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodFrom">From <span asp-validation-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodFrom" class="alert-danger"></span></label>
            <input asp-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodFrom" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodTo">To <span asp-validation-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodTo" class="alert-danger"></span></label>
            <input asp-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodTo" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">START VOTING PERIOD</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

### Action Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(BragOptionViewModel model)
    {
        if (! ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(nameof(BragManagementController.Index), model);
        }

        if (! _bragOptionService.IsVotingPeriodFromValid(model.CreateBragOptionViewModel))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("PeriodFrom", "The date you have entered should not be in the future");
            return View(nameof(BragManagementController.Index), model);
        }

        if (!_bragOptionService.IsVotingPeriodToValid(model.CreateBragOptionViewModel))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("PeriodTo", "The date you have entered should not be in the past");
            return View(nameof(BragManagementController.Index), model);
        }

        _bragOptionRepository.CreateVotingPeriod(_bragOptionService.LoadBragOption(model.CreateBragOptionViewModel));

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(BragManagementController.Index), "BragManagement");
    }
```

### view models

```
public class CreateBragOptionViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PeriodFrom { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PeriodTo { get; set; }
}

 public class BragOptionViewModel
{
    public CreateBragOptionViewModel CreateBragOptionViewModel { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MMM 0:d, yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime VotingPeriodTo { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{MMM 0:d, yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime VotingPeriodFrom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you add the CreateBragOptionViewModel prefix before each property, I believe you don't have to

Also, you should include the JQuery Ajax JS files to enable Client SIde Validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haitham's comment points to the right path. Based on your code, I think that you are looking for both unobtrusive client side validation as well as a display of the validation summary in the event that the ModelState.IsValid property is false or there are programmer defined logic constraints that can't be detected until the model data reaches the controller.

In the asp.net core docs, it looks like most of this information is covered in the following link:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation.html?highlight=validation

**Client Side Unobtrusive Validation** Needs both the javascript libraries and the correct HTML markup and attributes. The markup is auto-matically added in VS when you allow VS to create a strongly typed view that is bound to your model or viewmodel class.

**JAVASCRIPT libraries In Order For Unobtrusive Validation**

- jquery.js (or min)
- jquery.validate.js (or min)
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js (or min)

**HTML Markup**

Spans after the input elements can display client side validation errors, in your code it would be something like adding spans with

```
<span asp-validation-for="<your model property>"></span>
```

Ex).

```
   <label asp-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodFrom">From <span asp-validation-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodFrom" class="alert-danger"></span></label>
    <input asp-for="CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodFrom" class="form-control">
<span asp-validation-for=""CreateBragOptionViewModel.PeriodFrom"></span>
```

Additionally, if you don't have a client side input error but you add an error to the ModelState manually after the data reaches the controller, you can display or render the model error data in a div with the validation-summary attribute inside your form when the model is returned to the view.

```
<form class="form-inline-custom" asp-controller="BragOption" asp-action="Create" method="post" role="form">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
```